# Netgear GS724Tv3 and link aggregation Mac OS X Server 10.6.8

Tags: aggregation

I need to link aggregate 2 sets of ports on the Netgear GS724T with my Apple server tower (latest generation). I have 2 built in ports and 2 ports on a PCIe ethernet card.

It is not obvious to me how to properly configure the Netgear end. I have access to the Netgear box through its web interface, just don't know how to properly set the settings.

I tried going to Netgear for help, but they said my software support has expired. I bought this unit on their recommendation - they say it is compatible with 802.3ad protocol. I cannot locate any references to this protocol in the manual and I noticed some people in formus say that this device is actually not compatible with 802.3ad and that Netgear is misleading potential customers by saying it is.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

M

My own answer - posted as edit because of restrictions on my user:

OK folks, turns out one must use a Windows machine on this one or nothing makes sense. I was unable to get much farther than viewing the default inactive LAGs because in Firefox and Safari on Mac things don't make much sense - i.e. the Apply buttons (supposedly JavaScript) don't work. You can view the configurations, but none of the modifications you make stick.

Then, in Switching - LAGs, choose the ports to include and make sure you switch the LAG type from Static to LACP and all is well. Haven't tested the performance of the config yet, but both sides appear to be happy with the configuration. Apple server says link active and so does the Netgear.

Will report if any other discoveries.

Thanks for all who read and to user84104 for responding.

M

Answer (score 0):

IEEE 802.3ad is also know as [LACP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Aggregation_Control_Protocol).
Apparently Netgear thought it would be better to call it LAG.

On the [netgear](http://documentation.netgear.com/gs700t/enu/202-10484-02/usermanual.pdf):
`Switching > LAG`